# Microsoft Excel 2016 T - tests

Tags: excel-formula

I am using Microsoft Excel 2016 for data analysis, I can carry out the test fine but I cannot produce the t value along with my P value?

Answer (score 1):

The function `T.INV` can be used to get the critical values. The documentation describes that it "Returns the left-tailed inverse of the Student's t-distribution." Thus, e.g. `T.INV(0.05,9)` returns the value `-1.83311`. The corresponding right-tailed value `ABS(T.INV(0.05,9)) = 1.83311` returns the right-tailed version of it which is more traditionally used in stats books.

There is also a function `T.INV.2T` which you might prefer if you are using a 2-tailed T-test.

The dots in function names like `T.INV` are unusual in Excel naming conventions. The reason behind it is that for about a decade Excel used statistical functions which were mathematically correct but had implementations that were not numerically stable. These tended to be fine in 99% of the cases but would sometimes behave poorly when applied to values which were several standard deviations away from the mean. Eventually Microsoft responded to persistent criticism and (with Excel 2010?) completely revamped its statistical functions. The old version were kept as is for reasons of backwards. The new versions have similar names in most cases but use a dot. For example `T.INV` is a more modern, more numerically stable, version of the old `TINV`. Whenever you have a choice between using two similarly named statistical functions, use the one with the dot.